# How to confirm if RAM is being utilized completely?

Tags: linux, memory, resource-usage

I had 8GB of RAM on my motherboard (H81). I added another 8GB of same company, same model (HyperX Fury 8GB DDR3 1866MHz). The system is detecting both the RAMs and now showing as 16GB (15.5 to be more precise). But no matter how memory-intense tasks I perform the **usage** is never going above 7GB.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Last heavy task I performed was extracting a 35GB file while multiple tabs were open in Chrome and Firefox. The RAM usage didn’t go above 7 GB. I tried performing several other heavy tasks together but usage is always below 7GB.

Is it possible that — despite both of them being recognized and supported — both the RAM sticks are not being utilized?

[image]

Comment: I think you just have the wrong impression of how memory-intensive various operations are. That being said, your memory is fully used: As cache. It’s the yellow-ish color in `htop`.